# symfony 1.4 - is there a way to get text only of renderError() in a template?

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

I am trying to learn symfony.. can someone please tell me if there is a similar method like `renderErrorText()`? because this method `renderError()` outputs html with an ul/li tag. I just want the text of the error and not its html.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your own decorator. The `renderError` use a preformatted format to display an html renderer.

Create a file like `lib/form/sfWidgetFormSchemaFormatterMyFormatter.class.php`:

```
<?php

class sfWidgetFormSchemaFormatterMyFormatter extends sfWidgetFormSchemaFormatter
{
  protected
    $rowFormat                 = '',
    $helpFormat                = '%help%',
    $errorRowFormat            = '%errors%',
    $errorListFormatInARow     = "  <ul class=\"error_list\">\n%errors%  </ul>\n",
    $errorRowFormatInARow      = "    <li>%error%</li>\n",
    $namedErrorRowFormatInARow = "    <li>%name%: %error%</li>\n",
    $decoratorFormat           = '',
    $widgetSchema              = null,
    $translationCatalogue      = null;
```

And inside this class, you can define how to format and render an error.

Then, you will need to define this class a the default formatter for your form. If this is about your frontend environment, in `apps/backend/config/frontendConfiguration.class.php`:

```
class frontendConfiguration extends sfApplicationConfiguration
{
  public function configure()
  {
    sfWidgetFormSchema::setDefaultFormFormatterName('MyFormatter');
  }
}
```

Or if you want to it to be global to your project, in `config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php`:

```
class ProjectConfiguration extends sfProjectConfiguration
{
    public function setup()
    {
        sfWidgetFormSchema::setDefaultFormFormatterName('MyFormatter');
    }
}
```

You will find :

- [a documented example here](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/more-with-symfony/1_4/en/06-Advanced-Forms#chapter_06_custom_styling_when_a_form_element_has_an_error)
- [an example for twitter bootstrap](https://gist.github.com/emarref/3972392)